# Inserting binary notation of numbers in python list

Tags: python

I'm trying to do something like :

`x = [1001, 0111, 1111]`

I'm currently trying to do this as saving all values(decimal) in list arry and then trying to convert it to its binary notation using  :

`'{:04b}'.format(arry)`

Stuck at how to add another element after i inserted one. I have tried to do using append() and + but append() is not going to work and using + will cause all the binary format to glue together, how i should achieve this.
Thanks
Edit :

```
 x  = []
 x  = '{:04b}'.format(10)
 print(x)
 k = '{:04b}'.format(2)
 x.append(k)
```

Gives err:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "append.py", line 6, in <module>
 x.append(k)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Comment: Show the code, `append` should work if you were appending to the list and not to the string.

Comment: Searching for the err occurred. But i'm appending to the list directly.

Comment: You're reassigning `x` to a `string` on the 2nd line of your example code.

Comment: Thanks got it.  Oh i was neglecting that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you insert the first element into the list, you should be using `append` for that as well:

```
x  = []
x.append('{:04b}'.format(10))
print(x)
x.append('{:04b}'.format(2))
print(x)
```

---

Alternatively, you could build the list in different ways... e.g. a list comprehension:

```
x = ['{:04b}'.format(y) for y in (10, 2)]
```

This has the advantage of scaling nicely to an arbitrary number of integers.

---

Edit (in response to comments):

If you really just want to format some numbers as binary inside a list, you *can* do it pretty easily using a simple class:

```
class BinFormatter(object):
    def __init__(self, v):
        self.v = v
    def __repr__(self):
        return '{:04b}'.format(self.v)

print([BinFormatter(v) for v in (10, 2)])
```

However, be aware that this goes against conventional norms regarding the `__repr__` method which is generally supposed to provide the information necessary to reconstruct the object as much as is possible (in this case, the `__repr__` method is dropping *type* information, so you wouldn't have enough information to reconstruct the object.)...

Comment: Is it possible to get away with the initial  ' and tailing  ' as ['1010', '0010']
which is string can i get like [1010,0010] ??

Comment: @user2754673 -- That really depends on what you're looking for.  Python won't print integers like that automatically.  You _could_ create a special class that _represents_ itself like that, but it would be some work to get it to behave like an integer in any other respect... What are you going for here?

Comment: i just need it in [1000,0011] format. Actually was writing prog in C and printing binary was causing some problem as it was inside two for loops and model checker was unable to unwind as there were too many conversions required, so i was thinking to generate the same in python, i'm very unfamiliar with python. One thing i can do is generate ad then write script to get away with these ' ' . Thanks